# React query nested query key doesn't update correctly after mutation

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a query depending on a state and one mutation.

This is my query :

```
  const { isLoading, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["me", "notifications", filter],
    queryFn: () => getNotifications(filter),
  });
```

`filter` can be either `all` or `archive`.

This is my mutation :

```
const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => archiveNotification(notification?.id),
    onSuccess: async () => {
      return queryClient
        .invalidateQueries({
          queryKey: ["me", "notifications"],
        })
        .then(() => onClose());
    },
  });
```

When mutation ends, it correctly refresh the filter I'm looking (for example if I look at the page with `all` it gets updated after loading. But when I'm changing filter to `archive` data are the old one, and it makes the background refetch and then it displays correctly the new data, but there is a latency.

I would exepect that when I've already been looking at both filter, if I invalidate the query omitting the filter, it would refetch both queries, and then I would already have fresh data when changing filter.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect that when I've already been looking at both filter, if I invalidate the query omitting the filter, it would refetch both queries, and then I would already have fresh data when changing filter.

That's not quite right. React-Query won't re-query for an invalidated query key until some component is actually requesting the data. If instead you rendered two versions of the component (one showing "archive" and one showing "all") at the same time, you'd see them both update when you invalidate the query. But the library won't refetch anything until some component asks it to (with useQuery on the query key).

Comment: In a certain way, it's logical since it avoid to refetch tons of query if the app is big enough. Thank's for answering and clarity !

Comment: adding to the answer: if you want to refetch everything, you can add `refetchType: 'all'` to the query invalidation: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientinvalidatequeries